# Identify the abelian group that has the given presentation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, abelian-groups

For the presentation matrices  $$ \begin{bmatrix} 
0 \\
5\\
\end{bmatrix} , 
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1\\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$
identify the abelian group they represent.

For the first one I got $\Bbb{Z}$ and the second one I was wondering if I can simplify it to $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \end{bmatrix}$ and then get $\Bbb{Z/1Z}$. Any help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 2):

If an abelian group $G$ is generated by a set $(v_1, v_2, v_3)$ whose elements satisfy some relations, say

$$
a_{11}v_1+a_{21}v_2+a_{31}v_3=0;\\
a_{12}v_1+a_{22}v_2+a_{23}v_3=0;\\
a_{13}v_1+a_{23}v_2+a_{33}v_3=0;\\
a_{14}v_1+a_{24}v_2+a_{34}v_3=0,
$$
then the presentation matrix $A$ of $G$ is defined by

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
        a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14} \\
        a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24} \\
        a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34} \\
        \end{bmatrix}.$$
More generally, $G$ may be generated by $n$ elements that satisfy $m$ relations. This is just an example with $n=3$ and $n=4$.

Now, if the $j$th column of the matrix $A$ is $e_i$ (i.e., the row with zeros everywhere except for position $i$ where the element $1$ is present), then one may cross out the $i$th row and the $j$th column. The resulting matrix will present the same group. Indeed, a column that is equal to $e_i$ corresponds to the relation $v_i=0$. There is no sense in keeping the zero element in a generating set, so you may delete $v_i$ from your generating set and from the relations.

Let's turn to your examples. The group presented by the first matrix $\begin{bmatrix}
        0  \\
        5 
        \end{bmatrix}$ is generated by a set $(v_1, v_2)$. The only relation in this group is $5v_2=0$. It follows that the group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$.

Now for the second matrix. By what I said above, you may cross out the $1$st row and the $1$st column in the second matrix, obtaining  $\begin{bmatrix}
        1  \\
        0 
        \end{bmatrix}$. This matrix presents a group generated by a set $(v_1, v_2)$. The generators satisfy the relation $v_1=0$, so again by the above you may delete the generator $v_1$. Thus, you end up with a group generated by one element that satisfies no relation. This group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$. Alternatively, even without simplifying the matrix, you could have noted that the group corresponding to the original matrix is generated by a set $(v_1, v_2, v_3)$ and that the relations in the group are $v_1=0$ and $v_2=0$. So you get $\mathbb{Z}$ again.